# Пакуют или запаковывают?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как вы думаете, как правильнее сказать: "пакуют что-то в коробки" или "запаковывают"? И есть ли между этими словами смысловая разница?
Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Словари не указывают различий в значении слов "паковать, запаковывать, упаковывать", но определенная разница  в их применении все-таки существуют.

Приставка ЗА придает глаголу значение завершенности действия, а приставка У - значение "уместить что-либо в какое-либо пространство".

Паковать чемодан, паковать вещи в чемодан - эти действия можно соотнести с глаголом собирать чемодан или вещи в чемодан,  упаковывать - это укладывать  чемодан или размещать в нем вещи, а запаковывать - это, скорее, относится к вещам,  которым подбирается какая-либо упаковка.